# C# DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to create a c# application which tries  to connect and query the MySql Database. Below is the piece of code that I am using

```
public static void ValidateName(MySqlConnection conn,List<Employee> EmpList, string Group)
 {
 string selectQuery = "Select Name from Employee where Group = @Group  AND @Name in (FirstName, LastName);";
 using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Group", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
 for (int i = 0; i < EmpList.Count; i++)
 {
    cmd.Parameters["@Group"].Value = Group;
    cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = EmpList[i].Name;
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    List<string> lineList = new List<string>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        lineList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
    }
    if (lineList.Count <=0)
    {
       WriteValidationFailure(EmpList[i], "Failed");
    }}
```

It now throws error in the statement

```
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

[image]

Comment: From where this MySqlConnection conn is coming?

Comment: Just marked as duplicate since it is same question and I had answered it in the original

Comment: It seems like you haven't disposed the 'conn' object after having used it before.